# How to call jquery function with a href

Tags: jquery, function, tooltip, call, tiptip

I am using Jquery tiptip plugin. I want to call deactive_tiptip function with clicking a href link. How can i do that ?

I will call that function inside tooltip div.

This is the code of tiptip plugin

```
    /*
 * TipTip
 * Copyright 2010 Drew Wilson
 * www.drewwilson.com
 * code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin
 *
 * Version 1.3   -   Updated: Mar. 23, 2010
 *
 * This Plug-In will create a custom tooltip to replace the default
 * browser tooltip. It is extremely lightweight and very smart in
 * that it detects the edges of the browser window and will make sure
 * the tooltip stays within the current window size. As a result the
 * tooltip will adjust itself to be displayed above, below, to the left 
 * or to the right depending on what is necessary to stay within the
 * browser window. It is completely customizable as well via CSS.
 *
 * This TipTip jQuery plug-in is dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */

(function($){
    $.fn.tipTip = function(options) {
        var defaults = { 
            activation: "hover",
            keepAlive: false,
            sticky: false,
            maxWidth: "200px",
            edgeOffset: 3,
            defaultPosition: "bottom",
            delay: 400,
            fadeIn: 200,
            fadeOut: 200,
            attribute: "title",
            content: false, // HTML or String to fill TipTIp with
            enter: function(){},
            exit: function(){}
        };
        var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // Setup tip tip elements and render them to the DOM
        if($("#tiptip_holder").length <= 0){
            var tiptip_holder = $('<div id="tiptip_holder" style="max-width:'+ opts.maxWidth +';"></div>');
            var tiptip_content = $('<div id="tiptip_content"></div>');
            var tiptip_arrow = $('<div id="tiptip_arrow"></div>');
            $("body").append(tiptip_holder.html(tiptip_content).prepend(tiptip_arrow.html('<div id="tiptip_arrow_inner"></div>')));
        } else {
            var tiptip_holder = $("#tiptip_holder");
            var tiptip_content = $("#tiptip_content");
            var tiptip_arrow = $("#tiptip_arrow");
        }

        return this.each(function(){
            var org_elem = $(this);
            if(opts.content){
                var org_title = opts.content;
            } else {
                var org_title = org_elem.attr(opts.attribute);
            }
            if(org_title != ""){
                if(!opts.content){
                    org_elem.removeAttr(opts.attribute); //remove original Attribute
                }
                var timeout = false;

                if(opts.activation == "hover"){
                    org_elem.hover(function(){
                        active_tiptip();
                    }, function(){
                        if(!opts.keepAlive){
                            deactive_tiptip();
                        }
                    });
                    if(opts.keepAlive){
                        tiptip_holder.hover(function(){}, function(){

                        });
                    }
                } else if(opts.activation == "focus"){
                    org_elem.focus(function(){
                        active_tiptip();
                    }).blur(function(){
                        deactive_tiptip();
                    });
                } else if(opts.activation == "click"){
                    org_elem.click(function(){
                        active_tiptip();
                        return false;
                    }).hover(function(){},function(){
                        if(!opts.keepAlive){
                            deactive_tiptip();
                        }
                    });
                    if(opts.keepAlive){
                        tiptip_holder.hover(function(){}, function(){

                        });
                    }
                }

                function active_tiptip(){
                    opts.enter.call(this);
                    tiptip_content.html(org_title);
                    tiptip_holder.hide().removeAttr("class").css("margin","0");
                    tiptip_arrow.removeAttr("style");

                    var top = parseInt(org_elem.offset()['top']);
                    var left = parseInt(org_elem.offset()['left']);
                    var org_width = parseInt(org_elem.outerWidth());
                    var org_height = parseInt(org_elem.outerHeight());
                    var tip_w = tiptip_holder.outerWidth();
                    var tip_h = tiptip_holder.outerHeight();
                    var w_compare = Math.round((org_width - tip_w) / 2);
                    var h_compare = Math.round((org_height - tip_h) / 2);
                    var marg_left = Math.round(left + w_compare);
                    var marg_top = Math.round(top + org_height + opts.edgeOffset);
                    var t_class = "";
                    var arrow_top = "";
                    var arrow_left = Math.round(tip_w - 12) / 2;

                    if(opts.defaultPosition == "bottom"){
                        t_class = "_bottom";
                    } else if(opts.defaultPosition == "top"){ 
                        t_class = "_top";
                    } else if(opts.defaultPosition == "left"){
                        t_class = "_left";
                    } else if(opts.defaultPosition == "right"){
                        t_class = "_right";
                    }

                    var right_compare = (w_compare + left) < parseInt($(window).scrollLeft());
                    var left_compare = (tip_w + left) > parseInt($(window).width());

                    if((right_compare && w_compare < 0) || (t_class == "_right" && !left_compare) || (t_class == "_left" && left < (tip_w + opts.edgeOffset + 5))){
                        t_class = "_right";
                        arrow_top = Math.round(tip_h - 13) / 2;
                        arrow_left = -12;
                        marg_left = Math.round(left + org_width + opts.edgeOffset);
                        marg_top = Math.round(top + h_compare);
                    } else if((left_compare && w_compare < 0) || (t_class == "_left" && !right_compare)){
                        t_class = "_left";
                        arrow_top = Math.round(tip_h - 13) / 2;
                        arrow_left =  Math.round(tip_w);
                        marg_left = Math.round(left - (tip_w + opts.edgeOffset + 5));
                        marg_top = Math.round(top + h_compare);
                    }

                    var top_compare = (top + org_height + opts.edgeOffset + tip_h + 8) > parseInt($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop());
                    var bottom_compare = ((top + org_height) - (opts.edgeOffset + tip_h + 8)) < 0;

                    if(top_compare || (t_class == "_bottom" && top_compare) || (t_class == "_top" && !bottom_compare)){
                        if(t_class == "_top" || t_class == "_bottom"){
                            t_class = "_top";
                        } else {
                            t_class = t_class+"_top";
                        }
                        arrow_top = tip_h;
                        marg_top = Math.round(top - (tip_h + 5 + opts.edgeOffset));
                    } else if(bottom_compare | (t_class == "_top" && bottom_compare) || (t_class == "_bottom" && !top_compare)){
                        if(t_class == "_top" || t_class == "_bottom"){
                            t_class = "_bottom";
                        } else {
                            t_class = t_class+"_bottom";
                        }
                        arrow_top = -12;                        
                        marg_top = Math.round(top + org_height + opts.edgeOffset);
                    }

                    if(t_class == "_right_top" || t_class == "_left_top"){
                        marg_top = marg_top + 5;
                    } else if(t_class == "_right_bottom" || t_class == "_left_bottom"){     
                        marg_top = marg_top - 5;
                    }
                    if(t_class == "_left_top" || t_class == "_left_bottom"){    
                        marg_left = marg_left + 5;
                    }
                    tiptip_arrow.css({"margin-left": arrow_left+"px", "margin-top": arrow_top+"px"});
                    tiptip_holder.css({"margin-left": marg_left+"px", "margin-top": marg_top+"px"}).attr("class","tip"+t_class);

                    if (timeout){ clearTimeout(timeout); }
                    timeout = setTimeout(function(){ tiptip_holder.stop(true,true).fadeIn(opts.fadeIn); }, opts.delay); 
                }

                function deactive_tiptip(){
                    opts.exit.call(this);
                    if (timeout){ clearTimeout(timeout); }
                    tiptip_holder.fadeOut(opts.fadeOut);
                }
            }               
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without fully going through your code you can do this with a jquery selector.

so something like this;

```
$("a").live({click:function(){ //hide the tooltip at this point });
```

you need to use live if you are building the tooltips dynamically

However, this will run the code on (any) anchor.

Another way would be to decorate all the pertinent anchors with a class.

class="HideOnClick" and then use the jQuery;

```
$(".HideOnClick").live({click:function(){ //hide the tooltip at this point });
```

Comment: i tried like this but when i clicked gave un defined error      $(".HideOnClick").live({ click: function () { deactive_tiptip() } });

Answer (score 27):

You have "2" options (there are more depending on exactly how you want to do it)

1:

```
<a href="javascript:deactive_tiptip();">Visible Text</a>
```

2:

```
<a href="#" onclick="deactive_tiptip();">Visible Text</a>
```

Generally option one is better because it doesn't add a # to url upon click... but if you wanted to do an on hover instead of a click you'd use option 2 (replacing onclick with onmouseover)

You could also use JQuery:

```
$('#urlid').click(deactive_tiptip());

// Or newest way:
$('#urlid').on('click', deactive_tiptip);
```

Comment: Without personally testing these here are some things to try: 
1) $('#urlid').tipTip().deactive_tiptip();
2) $('#urlid').deactive_tiptip();
3) $('#urlid').unbind();
4) $('#urlid').die();

You can use it in either case 1 or 2 of my original example

Comment: perfect !! Thank u.